# PHP Image upload limit aspect ratio and allow only images with dimensions >= 600px

Tags: php, image, math, upload, aspect

I want to restrict any images uploaded to an aspect ratio of 1. These images should also have a minimum height/width of 600px. My problem is that my javascript `cropper(slimimagecropper)` sometimes produces images with dimensions of 599x600px or 598x600px. To solve this problem I wanted to allow a **tolerance of +-3px.**
I check the aspect ratio as follows:

```
if (abs(1 - ($image->width() / $image->height())) <= 0.009) { //... }
```

But now the greater the image (for example 700x700) the greater is the tolerance (7px).

Does someone know a better way to check for the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspect ratio of 1:1 means width equals height. So you want to check whether the difference between width and height exceeds 3px. Checking minimum dimensions would be a separate check.

If you want to also have ratios other than 1:1, you need to decide where the difference should apply. For example, for 4:3 a height difference of 3px would correspond to a width difference of 4px. So if you want to be lenitent and allow a 3px difference on the smaller edge, you'd write something like

```
abs($img->width()*3/4 - $img->height()) <= 3
```

whereas if you want to be strict and have the 3px threshold on the larger edge, you'd instead write

```
abs($img->width() - $img->height()*4/3) <= 3
```

Doing the multiplication before the division (i.e. `(height*4)/3` instead of `height*(4/3)` should avoid some of the surprises floating point arithmetic can bestow on you, and should make the case of equality a bit more reliable. If you decide to treat the aspect ratio as a single number, be aware that e.g. 4/3 has no exact representation as a binary floating point number, so do expect rounding errors. Consider changing your threshold to `3.5` or `3.1` or whatever, so that a mathematically exact difference of 3px won't fail due to rounding.

Comment: First of all thank you! Yes, you're right but I want to expand this function to also allow uploading of 16/9 4/3 etc images, and as far as I know this method doesn't work there

Comment: @Syntaax: If you want other aspect ratios, you should have made that requirement a part of your question, and not asked for a too-simple special case. Anyway, I extended my answer to deal with other aspects.